# NuxtJS how to reload asyncData with emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to know if it is possible to reload `asyncData` in an emit in a function like this

`Page`

```html
<template>
  <component-child :products="products" @asyncData="asyncData" />
</template>
```

```js
async asyncData({ $axios, store }) {
  const customerId = store.getters['user/auth/customerId'];
  if (!customerId) {
    return;
  }
  const products = await customerApi.getProducts(
    { $axios },
    customerId,
  );
  return {
    products: products
  };
},
```

`component-child`

```js
methods: {
  infiniteHandler() {
    this.$emit('asyncData);
  }
}
```

Is it possible? Otherwise how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `this.$nuxt.refresh()` to refresh `fetch()` or `asyncData()` hooks.
As explained in the documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/concepts/context-helpers#refreshing-page-data